# Vue + Typescript vue-router and type of params

Tags: typescript, parameters, vue-router

I'm trying to send some data from one component to other, but I have some problem with types.
This is my code:

```
const someData: object = {
   param1: 'param1',
   param2: 'param2',
   array: [{},{}]
}
this.$router.push({ name: 'SomePage', params: { someData } })
```

I get the data this way:

```
  get param1 (): string {
    return this.$route.params.someData['param1']
  }
  get param2 (): string {
    return this.$route.params.someData['param2']
  }
  get array (): Array<object> {
    return this.$route.params.someData['array']
  }
```

And the error from console:

```
Argument of type '{ name: string; params: { someData: object; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RawLocation'.
  Type '{ name: string; params: { someData: object; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Location'.
    Types of property 'params' are incompatible.
      Type '{ someData: object; }' is not assignable to type 'Dictionary<string>'.
        Property 'someData' is incompatible with index signature.
          Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

It works only if I put type `any` to `someData`, but I don't won't to use it.
How can I solve this problem? What is this `'Location'` and `'RawLocation'` type?

Comment: I am having the same issue. [Here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2662) is a GitHub issue that is related to this. There's a reply saying "For the moment, using always strings is the right way, the typings are good".

Comment: And about you, @MagnusTeekivi, check the answer

Answer (score 4):

Just what you can pass through pages as query parameters is a string type, not anything else. it means you can't send array by a query parameter.
you should change all your params to string

```
   const someData: object = {
      param1: 'stringType',
      param2: 'stringType',
      ...
   }
   this.$router.push({ name: 'SomePage', params: { someData } })
```

Instead of query parameter by `vux` you can save and datatype and use it everywhere you want, in my opening, I would be much better because at the same time your can manage passed data by your own

and about you @MagnusTeekivi
you can cast it to string after than you can use it, like this

```
`this.$router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId.toString() })`
```